# ¿se puede acceder a los miembros de un objeto definido como parametro en una funcion generica?

Tags: c++, template

Buenas

Estoy  creando un método miembro de una clase, que me permita recibir un objeto y guardar la información del objeto en un archivo.

```
MyClase::guardarDatos(Objeto a);
```

Específicamente necesito guardar tres objetos  que se derivan de una clase padre.
debido a que no deseo sobrecargar el método tres veces, e decidido crear una función, de tal forma que reciba un  objeto mediante el uso de template.

```
template<class T> 
MyClase::guardarDatos(T &a);
```

dentro de esta función obtengo el nombre de la clase entrante:

```
MyClase::guardarDatos(T &a){
const type_info &tip = typeid(a);};
```

con esto realizo una serie de validaciones para obtener los respectivos datos de cada objeto:

`if (tip.name() == "Objeto") {
 Datos1 d1= a.getDatos();
}else if(tip.name() == "Objeto1"){
Datos2 d2=a.getDatos();
}`

el problema es cuando intento acceder a una funcion miembro de `a` EJ: `a.getDatos()`, el compilador me arroja el siguiente mensaje:

> error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from

Supongo que en la compilación el tipo `T` sera interpretado como mi `Objeto`, por ello debería evitar este tipo de errores,

Agradezco su ayuda y guía.

Comment: ¿`cannot conver from` que? ¿Podrías añadir el error completo?

Comment: El problema que tiene es que al especializarse el template no puede cumplirse que el tipo de `a.getDatos` sea a la vez `Datos1` y `Datos2`. Los `if` de la función se compilan todos a la vez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problema.

> error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from

No has puesto el error completo ni has señalado en qué línea salta el error así que sólo podemos hacer conjeturas. Una rápida [búsqueda del error](https://www.google.es/search?q=error+C2440:+%27initializing%27:+cannot+convert+from.com#q=error+C2440:+%27initializing%27:+cannot+convert+from) nos descubre que estás usando [MSVC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B) para compilar y que podrías tener uno de [los siguientes errores](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/sy5tsf8z.aspx):

1. Inicializar un `char*` o `wchar_t*` no constante mediante un literal de cadena.
2. Intentar convertir un puntero a miembro a puntero a `void`.
3. Intentar usar de manera completa una clase declarada pero no definida.
4. Usar incorrectamente una conversión definida por el usuario.
5. Otros usos incorrectos específicos de MSVC.

Sin saber más detalles apuesto que tu fallo es el 3 o el 4, ya que en el código:

```
if (tip.name() == "Objeto") {
    Datos1 d1= a.getDatos();
}else if(tip.name() == "Objeto1"){
    Datos2 d2=a.getDatos();
}
```

Estás usando los tipos `Datos1` y `Datos2`, si no defines ambos tipos o si no defines cómo el retorno de `a.getDatos()` se puede convertir a ambos tipos entonces tendrás este problema que describes.

Pero es imposible de saber a ciencia cierta sin ver más código. Con el código que has publicado se puede ver que tienes una aproximación a la [serialización](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializaci%C3%B3n) que no es considerada una buena práctica en algunos ámbitos. Además de estar confiando en la [introspección de tipos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introspecci%C3%B3n_de_tipos) mediante el operador dependiente de implementación [`typeid`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) tu implementación se salta los principios de [encapsulamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica)).

La introspección de tipos o *Run-time type information* (RTTI en Inglés) tiene importantes costes en tiempo de ejecución, además evaluar una expresión con `typeid` puede incurrir también en costes en tiempo de ejecución.

Exponer externamente a los datos de tu clase puede llegar a considerarse un [antipatrón de diseño](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipatr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o) si se hace sin necesidad. Asumo que después de serializar los datos querrás deserializarlos por lo que si expones métodos para leer datos internos también necesitarás métodos para escribirlos.

#### Tu pregunta.

> ¿se puede acceder a los miembros de un objeto definido como parametro en una funcion generica?

Se puede, siempre y cuando los miembros sean visibles y públicos o la función sea amiga del objeto; el tipo de función no cambia este hecho:

```
struct S { int miembro; };
class  C { int miembro; };

void guardarDatos(const S &s)
{
    std::cout << "vamos a guardar S: " << s.miembro << '\n';
    ...
}

void guardarDatos(const C &c)
{
    // Error, C::miembro es privado
    std::cout << "vamos a guardar C: " << c.miembro << '\n';
    ...
}

template <typename T>
void guardarDatos_plantilla(const T &t)
{
    std::cout << "vamos a guardar T: " << t.miembro << '\n';
    ...
}

S s; C c;
guardarDatos_plantilla(s);
guardarDatos_plantilla(c); // Error, C::miembro es privado

class C2
{
    int miembro;
    template <typename T> 
    friend void guardarDatos_plantilla(const T&);
    friend void guardarDatos(const C2 &);
};
```

En el ejemplo anterior, las funciones `guardarDatos_plantilla` o `guardarDatos` (sobrecarga con `C2`) no tendrán problemas para acceder a `C2::miembro` pese a ser privado ya que son funciones amigas de `C2`.

#### Propuesta.

Delega en los objetos las rutinas de serialización y deserialización en lugar de crear una clase externa para estos fines.

Mi aproximación consistiría en que cada objeto tuviese la capacidad de serializarse a si mismo, ya sea escribiendo directamente en archivo o devolviendo una versión binaria de sus datos y estado. Paralelamente cada objeto debería tener la capacidad de deserializarse a si mismo, ya sea leyendo directamente de un archivo o leyendo datos binarios:

```
class SerializableEnArchivo
{
    int miembro; 
    void serializar(std::ofstream archivo)
    {
        archivo << miembro;
    }

    void deserializar(std::ifstream archivo)
    {
        archivo >> miembro;
    }
};

using byte_buffer = std::vector<std::uint8_t>;

class SerializableEnBufer
{
    int miembro; 
    byte_buffer serializar()
    {
        byte_buffer datos{sizeof(miembro)};
        // serializar
        return datos;
    }

    void deserializar(const byte_buffer &datos)
    {
        // deserializar
    }
};
```

Puedes crear una interfaz a partir de estas ideas y heredar de la interfaz, pero debes pensar si eso te es conveniente:

```
struct Serializable
{
    using byte_buffer = std::vector<std::uint8_t>;

    virtual byte_buffer serializar() = 0;
    virtual void deserializar(const byte_buffer &) = 0;
};

class Clase : public Serializable { ... };
```

Comment: Gracias @PaperBirdMaster, me aclaras muchas cosas, entiendo que para mantener el principio de encapsula miento, se implementaría una lógica como la que propones.

Answer (score 0):

El diseño que estás haciendo es un poco pobre en cuanto a que su implementación implica un gran acoplamiento dentro del template... cuando se supone que los templates sirven para crear código específico. ¿Soluciones?

Si el conjunto de operaciones a realizar con `Datos1`, `Datos2`, ... son exactamente los mismos puedes generalizar la función. Para conseguir un código lo más limpio posible lo recomendable es centralizar la configuración fuera del template:

```
// Template base.
// Para tipos no especializados no compilará.
template<class T>
struct Configurador;

template<>
struct Configurador<Objeto1>
{
  typedef Datos1 TipoRetorno;
};

template<>
struct Configurador<Objeto2>
{
  typedef Datos2 TipoRetorno;
};
```

Este mecanismo es muy sencillo de escalar y deja el template más limpio:

```
template<class Objeto>
class MyClase
{
  // Cargamos el tipo esperado en nuestro objeto
  // typename hay que usarlo porque el tipo viene dado por un template.
  typedef typename Configurador<Objeto>::TipoRetorno TipoRetorno;

  void GuardarDatos(Objeto& obj)
  {
    TipoRetorno d = obj.getDatos();
    // ...
  }
};
```

Claro que a partir de C++11 podemos simplificar esta estructura usando `auto`. Dado que al usar `auto` se delega en el compilador la responsabilidad de asignar el tipo correcto, el código compilará correctamente.

```
template<class Objeto>
class MyClase
{
  void GuardarDatos(Objeto& obj)
  {
    auto d = obj.getDatos();
    // ...
  }
};
```

Por otro lado, si la lógica a ejecutar depende del tipo de objeto la opción puede ser externalizar dicha lógica:

```
template<class T>
void GuardarObjeto(T obj);

template<>
void GuardarObjeto<Objeto1>(Objeto1& obj)
{
  Datos1 d = obj.getDatos();
  // ...
}

template<>
void GuardarObjeto<Objeto2>(Objeto2& obj)
{
  Datos2 d = obj.getDatos();
  // ...
}

template<class Objeto>
class MyClase
{
  void GuardarDatos(Objeto& obj)
  {
    GuardarObjeto(obj);
  }
};
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias @eferion, si, las operaciones sobre los datos son las mismas. Como lo muestras en la **opcion1**. Solo tengo una pregunta, ¿que tan viable crees que es llevar una implementación de estas en una superclase?. Esto con el fin de llevar la propuesta de la primera respuesta y la tuya en una sola.

Comment: Si usas C++11 en adelante te puedes ahorrar la estructura `Configurador`, ya que con `auto` el tipo se deduce automáticamente, con lo cual solo necesitas una clase para gestionar el proceso.

Comment: gracias, empezare a trabajar.